# В PyCharm как настроить структуру программы?

Tags: python, математика, pycharm

В рамках учебного курса создал код в двух файлах. Один содержит два метода: функцию `func()` (в ней всего лишь записана другая функция `np.sin(x)`) и метод приближения функций `polynomial()`.

Второй файл реализует метод получения первой и второй производной `diffs()`. Там и там результатом работы программы являются свои таблицы с данными для каждой точки сетки.

Чтобы не дублировать код, во второй файл импортировал `polynomial`, `func` из первого (см. скрин). Но от того на выходе вместо таблицы `diffs()` я снова получаю таблицу `polynomial()`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более того: в обеих методах через `input()` запрашивается порядок `order`. **Так при реализации `diffs()` я теперь получаю двойной запрос порядка order!**

**Что мне надо в `diffs()` от `polynomial()`?** Сам `order`, списки `polinom_list` и `x_j_list`. Все эти переменные используются в расчетах функции.

Немного подробностей.

Функция `polynomial()` отдает через `return` три переменные:

`poly_table` — таблицу Pandas с параметрами для каждой точки сетки *(она нам во второй функции как переменная не нужна, хотя выскакивает аж в качестве итога работы функции)*,

`polinom_list` — список полиномиальных точек (одна из колонок таблицы Pandas),

`x_j_list` — список точек сетки.

Чтобы избавиться от повторного запроса переменной `order`, сделал ее четвертой переменной, которую отдает `polynomial()`. **Получил новую ошибку:**

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

Comment: Приведите сам код, демонстрирующий проблему.